# Can't export NFS already-mounted folder

Tags: linux, rhel, nfs

On my local network, I have a computer **A** mounting a folder from a remote location using nfs, let's call it folder **X**. Only **A** is able to access this remote location on the network.

Then, I have a computer **B** that needs to mount the folder **X**, but is not able to access it. The only way to do it right now is to perform an `SSH`/`SFTP` access from computer **A** to computer **B**, but we want a direct access.

The solution should be to perform an `NFS` export of folder **X** from computer **A** and to mount it from **B**, as these two computers are able to communicate.

I currently am able to export and mount computer **A** folders, but I get errors when trying to export folder **X** (certainly because it's already an nfs-mounted folder).

`exportfs` prints the following error when trying to export **X** folder:

> exportfs: /X does not support NFS export

`/var/log/messages` prints the following error:

> Jul 17 14:12:05 A rpc.mountd[17749]: refused mount request from B for /X (/): no export entry

Is it possible to perform exportation of an already NFS-exported folder?

Is there a better way to access folder **X** from **B** as if this folder is mounted locally on **B**?

All computers are running redhat.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: "_The solution should be to perform an NFS export of folder X from computer A and to mount it from B, as these two computers are able to communicate._". No. The solution is to allow both A and B to mount the NFS share from the remote location. If that's impossible please update your question to explain why so.

Comment: "_Is it possible to perform exportation of an already NFS-exported folder?_". No it's not, because you can only NFS export a local filesystem.

Comment: @roaima to be more correct NFS can only export **supported** file systems. NFS is obviously not supported. BTW some filesystems which *seem* to work may not work correctly. A few years ago I was surprised that not even ext4 was working as it should and NFS developers told me that it's not officially supported.

Comment: @rudimeier ah yes, agreed. (Although I didn't know about the ext4 issue.)

Answer (score -1):

On Debian (Maybe will work on RedHat)

Create empty folder on computer **A** named **X**

Use `/etc/fstab` and `exportfs -a` to export folder **A**

You must mount this empty folder into computer **B**

and **ONLY** after that :

mount your folder from your remote location using nfs into folder **X** on computer **A**

Regards