# Can't Export Any Directory Off My Home Directory - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, nfs

Whenever I make an NFS export on a folder off my home directory I get the error below (appreciate this example is too brief, but the next set of code shows how I got here):

```
$ sudo exportfs -ar
exportfs: /export/test does not support NFS export
```

Here is what I've done in detail:

```
## Create the bind mount ##
$ sudo  mount --bind /home/john/test /export/test

## Verify original /home/john/test folder exists ##
john@john:~/test$ cd ~/
john@john:~$ ls -l | grep test
drwxrwxr-x  2 john john  4096 Feb  9 13:33 test

## Check what files exist in this folder and confirm they are in the bind location ##
john@john:~$ cd test
john@john:~/test$ ls 
f  test  testfile

## Verify bind location folder exists & that the same files are in this location ##
john@john:~/test$ cd /export/test
john@john:/export/test$ ls
f  test  testfile

## Ensure export file is exporting the bind location ##
john@john:/export/test$ grep test /etc/exports
/export/test 192.168.0.0/24(rw,sync,root_squash,no_subtree_check)

## Re-export shares to get the /export/test nfs share on the network ##
john@john:/export/test$ sudo exportfs -ar
exportfs: /export/test does not support NFS export
```

As you can see.  When I try to re-export my share, it throws the error above.   After the testing below, I found that this only happens when trying to export anything linked, or directly on my /home/john/ directory.  I don't know why.

---

**#################### Testing using a directory outside of /home ######################**

**Here I try and use the NFS share on a new directory "/test" without a bind mount, and it works:**

```
#note, continuing from the bash commands above#
john@john:/test$ cd ..
john@john:/$ sudo umount /test
john@john:/$ ls /test
test
john@john:/$  sudo exportfs -ar
john@john:/$
```

---

**########## Testing using a share from a directory in /home (without a bind-mount)########**

**Here I made a share on a directory off of my home directory (as I suspect it's the home directory mounts having the issue), without any binds, which doesn't work**

```
john@john:~$ mkdir test-nobind
john@john:~$ cd test-nobind/
john@john:~/test-nobind$ touch file1 file2
john@john:~/test-nobind$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 0 Feb  9 19:23 file1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 0 Feb  9 19:23 file2
john@john:~/test-nobind$ cd ..
john@john:~$ sudo nano /etc/exports ###added line to export this folder
john@john:~$ grep test /etc/exports
/home/john/test-nobind 172.31.16.0/24(rw,sync,root_squash,no_subtree_check)

john@john:~$ sudo exportfs -rav
exporting 172.31.16.0/24:/home/john/test-nobind
exportfs: /home/john/test-nobind does not support NFS export
```

As you can see, I have the same error as my original post where exportfs says "does not support NFS export".  So it's my home directory causing the problem.  My /etc/crypttab file is empty, so I don't believe I have any encryption running (at least I don't think I do).  I want to know why I get this error?

---

Below is a list of stuff/outputs people in this forum have asked me to check

```
john@john:/home$ df $HOME
Filesystem            1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/home/john/.Private 106992680 81417972  20116688  81% /home/john

john@john:~$ mount | grep /home/john
/home/john/.Private on /home/john type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=b15035efe9091f4e,ecryptfs_sig=05afa3a5d0c7b155,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

Comment: possible that /home/john is *also* an NFS mount -- try `df $HOME` to confirm

Comment: I've pasted this  output into the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Hmm, and `mount | grep /home/john ` ?

Comment: updated my original post with the output (at bottom)

Comment: This home directory used to be encrypted a while ago.  I followed some guide on how to remove the encryption from the askubuntu forums.  Looks like your onto something in that direction.  I actually don't know how to solve this problem, because Ubuntu automagically encrypted my home drive.  It's part of the reason I hate Ubuntu; I don't know how to fix it because it just auto-does stuff rather than make me learn how to do it (so I can undo it).

Comment: Neither Ubuntu nor any other operating system automatically encrypts file systems. Encryption has to be specifically enabled by the user.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379055/cant-export-nfs-already-mounted-folder#comment673940_379055 -- I don't know, but perhaps NFS won't export ecryptfs?

Comment: A bug report that might be relevant: [ecryptfs does not work properly over nfs, cifs, samba, WebDAV, or aufs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/277578)